# mysql order by using file sort performance

Tags: mysql, sorting, filter

## SQL performance

Problem SQL has 7 tables join and sort by specific values ( about 50 values)

#### SQL

```
select a.col1 ~~
            /*+ skip */
     from tab1 a
     left outer join tab2 b on b.tab2_col1 = a.tab1_col2
     left outer join tab3 c on c.tab3_col1 = c.tab1_col2
     left outer join tab4 d on d.tab4_col1 = a.tab1_col2
     left outer join tab5 e on a.tab5_col1 = d.tab4_col2
     left outer join tab6 f on f.tab6_col1 = a.tab1_col1 
                               and f.tab6_col3 = 'Y' and f.tab6_col4 ='A'
     left outer join tab7 g on g.tab7.col1 = f.tab6_col2
     where a.col1 in ( == about 50 values  == )
     order by fields( a.col1, == about 50 values == )
```

#### SQL elapsed time

First time : 3 sec

Second time : 0.1 sec below

#### TABLE DESC

```
 table tab1 ( about 17,000,000 rows )
 tab1_col1 --- PK , auto increment
 tab1_col2 
 tab1_col3
 ...

 table tab2 ( about 10,000,000 rows )
 tab2_col1 -- PK
 tab2_col2 -- PK
 tab2_col3 -- PK

 table tab3 ( about 2,000,000 rows )
 tab3_col1 -- PK
 tab3_col2 
 tab3_col3 

 table tab4 ( about 3,000,000 rows )
 tab4_col1 -- PK
 tab4_col2 -- PK
 tab4_col3 

 table tab5 ( about 400 rows )
 tab5_col1 -- PK
 tab5_col2 -- PK
 tab5_col3 

 table tab6 ( about 30,000,000 rows )
 tab6_col1 -- PK
 tab6_col2 -- PK
 tab6_col3 
 tab6_col4

 table tab7 ( about 2,000,000 rows )
 tab7_col1 -- PK
 tab7_col2 
 tab7_col3
```

#### explain

[image]

#### question

first table access type is 'range' -- by primary key
     perhaps in statement makes it
     so 'order by' by primary key makes 'using file sort' 
     is right??

If it is right, how can i improve sql performance?

Comment: Using functions like `fields()` make using indexes impossible.

Comment: Rewrite it as Order by col1,col2,col3,etc..

Comment: And if you have to order by 50 columns there is something seriously wrong with your application.